# Viel taking "e" as ending when... playing role as an adverb

Tags: grammar-identification

> Was viele jedoch nicht wissen, ist, dass sie nach Annahmen einiger Experten und Mediziner vermutlich auch dafür verantwortlich sind, dass Weintrinker am nächsten Tag gelegentlich über Kopfschmerzen klagen dich nichts mit übermäßigem Alkholkonsum zu tun haben.

Why does viel have an ending as "e" in the above? I assumed it was an adjective since I can't see any noun it goes with.

Comment: Previous lookup somewhere - e. g.  [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/viel)  - and comparing the examples  helps to refine the question. You seem to provide just an assumption.

Comment: Now, how would I use that site to help me make a better question? @guidot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you used the word "viele" in your example it is just the counterpart to "viel", like "much" and "many" in English: you use "viel**e**" when you deal with countables, "viel" when you deal with amounts:

> viel Reis - much rice
> viele Reiskörner - many grains of rice

Answer (score 3):

Viele is not an adverb but a pronoun. It acts much like an nominalized adjective but, as a pronoun, it is not capitalized.

Comment: Now how did you figure that out

Comment: A good dictionary will have the information that *viel* can be used as a pronoun.